# How to pass a value from all previous frames (higher frames) to a lower frame during recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

To simplify asking my question, let us consider printing all permutations of an array, without repetition. So if {1,2,3} was the array, the output would be the following

```
1 2 3 
1 3 2 
2 1 3 
2 3 1 
3 1 2 
3 2 1 
count == 6
```

How can I pass a count of all the elements that are already part of the array to a frame lower. I mean, say, in the first two frames of recursion, I have elements 1 and 2 in my stack. I need to tell the frame below, that it can use all elements except for 1 and 2, since it's already used.

Please see my code below, where I pass an array of all encountered elements as part of the function call for the frame below. But I also have to save and restore the elements of the array for other recursive calls in the same frame, since Java does not save a copy of the array in each frame, and passing references causes the Array to get over-written.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SendfromHigherFrameToLowerFrame {
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3};

        int[] stack = new int[3];
        fun(a, stack, 0);

        System.out.println("count == "+count);
    }

    static void fun(int[] a, int[] stack, int frame)
    {
        if(a.length == frame)
        {
            count++;
            print(stack);
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            //save stack
            int[] temp = new int[stack.length];
            save(stack, temp);
            if(isValid(stack, a[i]) == true)
            {
                stack[frame] = a[i];
                fun(a, stack, frame+1);
                //restore stack
                restore(temp, stack);
            }
        }
    }

    static void save(int[] source, int[] destination)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<source.length;i++)
            destination[i] = source[i];
    }

    static void restore(int[] source, int[] destination)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<source.length;i++)
            destination[i] = source[i];
    }

    static boolean isValid(int[] a, int key)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == key)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void print(int[] a)
    {
        for(int x : a)
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Please suggest improvements to the code, or an easier way for passing elements down the call.

PS : Please note that generating permutations is not my original question, and I understand there are simpler ways to do it, it's solely for the purpose of conveying my question.

Comment: Why not to convert your methods to non-static then use a instance field?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to keep passing a primitive by reference in Java, you cannot simply make an `int`, and pass it down the invocation stack. There are three work-arounds to this issue:

- Use a mutable class, such as an array of a single `int`, or [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). This approach, however, borders on a misuse of arrays and mutable classes.
- Make an instance variable or a static variable, the way you did it. This is far from ideal, because your recursive function becomes non re-entrant, and so it is much harder to test.
- Return the modified value from the method, and add/assign it to a local variable inside the recursive method to pass down as its own return value. This approach is good, but it accommodates only a single return value, and requires you to be very careful when writing your code.

Here is how you function can be modified to implement the last approach described above:

```
static int fun(int[] a, int[] stack, int frame) {
    if(a.length == frame) {
        print(stack);
        return 1;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
        //save stack
        int[] temp = new int[stack.length];
        save(stack, temp);
        if(isValid(stack, a[i]) == true) {
            stack[frame] = a[i];
            res += fun(a, stack, frame+1);
            //restore stack
            restore(temp, stack);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qcSr3D)

**Note:** It goes without saying that your exercise does not need to do any of that, because `count` is always equal to `stack.length`.

Comment: for the third bullet you mentioned, could you please edit your answer with a pseudocode. I haven't got it completely.

Comment: Thanks. But small language check here. Consider a call stack such as fun(5);fun(4);fun(3);fun(2);fun(1);fun(0);. Here when I mean "higher frame" I mean, 5 and fun(4) is the lower frame. I was asking how a value can be passed from fun(5) to fun(4), fun(3), fun(2) all the way up to fun(0). That is, if an element is taken in fun(5), I need fun(0) as well to know that it's taken and cannot be used. I felt your third bullet point was more about 'return'ing from a lower frame to a higher frame, keeping it consistent with my usage of "lower" and "higher". ?

Comment: @saltandwater This can be addressed by passing around a reference to a mutable collection - for example, `Set<Integer>`. Top-level method would create it, and pass it down to lower levels. When a lower level modifies this collection before returning, the upper levels would see the modification. However, having a mutable state makes it harder to understand your recursive function.